# How do I update object properties by looping through each key?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on some quiz and I have these console logs here:

```
console.log(obj) => { cat: undefined, dog: undefined }
console.log(keys)` => [ 'cat', 'dog' ]
console.log(reversedKeys) =>[ 'tac', 'god' ]
```

I goal here is to update the object property. I'm doing this (trying to map through keys) but this code doesn't work. I just started learning javascript and clearly missing something in this code. The more I look to it the more I find just confusing myself.

```
keys.map(k => {
  reversedKeys.map(r => {
    obj[keys[k]] = r  
  }) 
return obj  
})
```

The expected result would be:`console.log(obj)` => `{ cat: tac, dog: god}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `for..in` loop to iterate object keys, spread element to convert property name to array, `.reverse()`, `.join()`

```js
let obj = { cat: undefined, dog: undefined };

for (let key in obj) {
  obj[key] = [...key].reverse().join("")
}

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `for..in` to iterate the object. Then use the split method to create an array of the characters used in the `key`. Use array [**reverse**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) method to reverse the array and `join` method to create the new string

```js
var obj = {
  cat: undefined,
  dog: undefined
}

for (var keys in obj) {
  obj[keys] = keys.split("").reverse().join("")
}
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the object, [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) might return an unexpected result since it would include enumerable properties in the prototype. To exclude those you could add an `if` statement with `obj.hasOwnProperty(key)` as the conditional:

```js
const obj = { cat: undefined, dog: undefined }
for (let key in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    obj[key] = key.split("").reverse().join("")
  }
}
console.log(obj)
```

You could also use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) which would not include the enumerable properties in the prototype like this:

```js
const obj = { cat: undefined, dog: undefined }
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
  obj[key] = key.split("").reverse().join("")
})
console.log(obj)
```